# ThreeJs: Can I hide and Unhide layers in a Json Model/OBJ Model with ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, blender, maya

My friend and I are working on a 3D configurator for shirts and I thought it will be the best if he creates a new model for each type of button that we have so that it look dynamic - in the same way, we created different type of models for different collars but he suggested that he could use something called a layer and create different button types on different layers and all I have to do is hide and unhide the layer depending on the button which user picks. I want to know if it is possible in Three.js to programmatically hide layers and if a mesh with layers can be imported into a Three.js project.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: you can hide and unhide obj model in three.js

Comment: i am not talking about hiding the model, i am talking about "Layers". Do you know anything about layers?

Comment: @Eshiett Something about layers is [here](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Layers). Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only solution, THREE.js (any release)

```
//one button
var mySingleButton = new THREE.Mesh()

//hide one button
mySingleButton.visible = false 

//show one button
mySingleButton.visible = true
```

To make layers:

```
var myLayer = [] //this is an array, you can think of it as a group of things or "layer" of things
for( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ){
   myLayer.push( new Mesh() ) //this is called a loop, it will create 10 meshes and store them in the group declared above
}
```

Later in the code when you want to hide them

```
//you can use the loop again
for( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ){
   myLayer[i].visible = false //with i you access the button in the layer and hide it
}
```

And then when you want to show them

```
  //you can use the loop again
for( var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ ){
   myLayer[i].visible = true 
}
```

If you want to export some model to three.js and you're not sure if it supports anything resembling "layers" you can make a convention. Instead of exporting a mesh called `button` you could call it `layer_0_button`. Using javascript you could differentiate this name from for example `layer_1_button`.